# How to use variables in query

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I have to use a user input value in my query to select a row which has that value........
I have written this code in qt but it doesn't work...how can I fix it?

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int j=0;
    float t;
    t=ui->T_lineEdit->text().toFloat();
    QSqlQuery qry;
    if(qry.exec("select * from table where te='+t+'"))
    {
        ui->u_lineEdit->setText("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: change `qry.exec("select * from table where te='+t+'")` to  `qry.exec(QString("select * from table where te='%1'").arg(t))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) using [`QSqlQuery`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html).

```
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("select * from table where te=?");
qry.addBindValue(t);

if(qry.exec())
{
    ui->u_lineEdit->setText("hello");
}
```

Note that concatenating user's raw string to a SQL query is highly vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: yeah, yeah, but he also needs to know what went wrong with what he tried to do.

Comment: @itsLex I disagree. Not thinking of SQL queries as being constructed by string concatenation is better than fixing the syntax of formatting a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familliar with qt, but it seems to me that you used concatenation within a string, so `"select * from table where te='+t+'"` should be `"select * from table where te='"+t+"'"` .

Of course it is strange that you should place single quotes around a `float` value, but I don't know the type of column `te`. It could be necessary to convert `t` to string first:

```
"select * from table where te='" + QString::number(t) + "'"
```

Finally I have to add that this looks suspiciously like code where you allow SQL Injection. You should look into this and make sure to avoid it. See Frogatto's answer for that.